# In Kubernetes, how many namespaces can you have?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use the Kubernetes namespace for each user of my application. So potentially I'll need to create thousands of namespaces each with kubernetes resources in them. I want to make sure this is scalable, so I want to ensure that I can have millions of namespaces on a Kubernetes Cluster before I use this construct on a per user basis.

I'm building a web hosting application. So I'm giving resources to each user, but I want them separated by namespaces.

**Are there any limitations to the number of Kubernetes namespaces you can create?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In majority of cases, thresholds are NOT hard limits - crossing the limit results in degraded performance and doesn't mean cluster immediately fails over.

Many of the thresholds (for cluster scope) are given for the largest possible cluster. For smaller clusters, the limits are proportionally lower.
"

#Namespaces = 10000  scope=cluster

[source](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-scalability/configs-and-limits/thresholds.md#kubernetes-thresholds) with more data

[kube Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_Ww6ELKl4Q) explaining how the data is computed

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually run into limitations with resources and etcd long before you hit a namespace limit.

For scaling, you're probably going to want to scale your clusters which most companies treat as cattle rather than create a giant cluster which will be a Pet, which is not a scenario you want to be dealing with.